# На одном листе в Excel есть 2 таблицы. Как извлечь вторую в отдельный датафрейм без указания номеров строк и столбцов с помощью Python?

Tags: python, excel

Есть 2 таблицы на листе Excel. Одна обыкновенная, которую можно прочитать с помощью Python. Вторая маленькая итоговая табличка, которая имеет  названия столбцов и строк. Причем, в первую таблицу могут добавляться данные и соответственно вторая табличка сдвигается по индексам строк. Как извлечь эту вторую табличку? Пробовала задать диапазон, но он строго привязан с номерам строк и столбцов. Подскажите, что можно сделать?

Comment: "*что можно сделать*" - для начала нужно полноценно описать задачу (исходные данные в текстовом виде) и показать свои попытки ее решить (в виде кода)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43367805/pandas-read-excel-multiple-tables-on-the-same-sheet#:~:text=Add%20a%20comment-,20,I%20wrote%20the%20following,-code%20to%20identify